# Delete StorageFile, which directly bind to view

Tags: c#, windows-8

In my Windows 8 App (C#+xaml) I have a lot of files(almost images) in `IsolatedStorage`. 
For displaying images I use direct binding to IS file like this:

```
public BitmapImage BitmapImage
{
    get
    {
       return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + FolderName + "/" + FileName));
    }
}
```

All works great. But when I want to delete files, which I currently displaying on page I have `UnauthorizedAccessException`. For deleting I use this:

```
 await storageFile.DeleteAsync();
```

My question is: I can not delete the file, because it is used for binding. How to make so that I could delete it?

Comment: Have you added the correct capabilities to your app?

Comment: yes. I can delete all files, which not bind to local fields. I think access denied, because my app use this file, and system can't delete it. I need some way to unbind or stop using this files;

Comment: I already use BitmapImage = null, but it doesn't work

Comment: @jimpanzer: Do you raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` when you set it to `null`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, of course.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image UriSource to null before the image itself ?

Comment: Although related to WPF, this may help http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18

Answer (score -1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13002322/1220781), you need to remove the image from the parent control to free the file resource.

```
grid.Children.Remove(BitmapImage);
BitmapImage = null;
```