# async and await image loading takes consume more memory in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

I'm working on Image gallery for window phone 8.1, where user can see images one by one like book of images. where you can turn image and view another image.

Right now, this gallery application consume to much memory and I'm getting out of memory exception after    some time while using application.

I'm using below code to load image into usercontrol.

```cs
StorageFile f1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx://" + Physical path of application for getting image);
using (IRandomAccessStream stream1 = await f1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
     bitmapImage1 = new BitmapImage();
     await bitmapImage1.SetSourceAsync(stream1);
     nextimg = bitmapImage1;
     stream1.Dispose();
}
```

Can anyone help to guide here regarding memory consumption?

Comment: Have you tried disposing the images which are not in the view anymore? For example, if you move to twentieth image in the gallery, you don't need to have the first one in the memory, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems that somebody already asked a similar question: [Memory not being relieved when setting BitmapImage to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988427/memory-not-being-relieved-when-setting-bitmapimage-to-null).

But still, I googled a little bit and found a complete investigation of the issue here: [Memory leak with BitmapImage](http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx). While it's worth reading, here are a few solutions suggested in this article.

1. Set your `BitmapImage`'s source to an empty stream, OR
2. Set your `BitmapImage.UriSource` to null, OR
3. When the image is opened (`BitmapImage.ImageOpened` event is raised), unsubscribe from `BitmapImage.ImageOpened` and `BitmapImage.ImageFailed` events.

And by the way, why do you call `stream1.Dispose()`? The `using` statement implies this call.

Comment: I'm developing on windows phone 8.1 and I'm not using Bitmapimage.ImageOpened and Image Failed Events. I'm setting bitmap image into imagebrush of grid background and also apply image animation like page turn in book

Comment: you can see in my code that I'm not using UriSource, so no need to set null to urisource.

Comment: @sikender It doesn't matter. Windows Runtime on Windows Phone 8.1 is almost the same as on Windows 8.1. What matters is what happens inside BitmapImage. If you read the article I linked, you will see that the native image buffer's reference is held by the class until you unsubscribe from those events. And if you use `SetSourceAsync`, it may very well be implemented using those events - and so you get an implicit subscription to those. Also, the buffer may be freed when setting a new source - and `UriSource` too. Give it a try before you decide it doesn't help.